# How do i call check value out of the function

Tags: ios, swift

How do i call the check value out of the function

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {
    let check = item

    if (check == 0) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } 
    else if (check == 1) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else if (check == 2) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        let vc6 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "wat") as! waterController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc6, animated: true)
    }
}
```

how do i call the check value out of the function

Comment: store selected item value in global variable and then you can check same condition outside the function. You can also create 1 method where you pass selected item value and check all condition inside it.

Comment: Are you asking how to return the check to the caller or how to take a function (that checks the selected item) as an argument?

Comment: What is your exact use case? Depending on that you might need to create a variable inside the class or a global variable.

Comment: i want to call the item value in another view controller . how do i do that