# calling the item value in pickerview into another view controller when the another viewcontroller loaded

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

i want to call the item value in pickerview(did you know view controller) into second view controller when the second view controller is loaded

```
class didYouKnowViewController:UIViewController,AKPickerViewDelegate,AKPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfItemsInPickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView) -> Int {
    return displayList.count
}

@IBOutlet var pickedName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var navbar: UINavigationBar!

func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, imageForItem item: Int) -> UIImage {
     pickedName.text = namesitem[item]
    return UIImage(named: displayList[item])!.imageWithSize(CGSize(width: 150, height: 200))
}
@IBOutlet var akPickerVIew: AKPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    akPickerVIew.delegate=self
    akPickerVIew.dataSource=self

    pickedName.text=namess[0]


}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {

   let  check = item


    if (check == 0) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController

                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)





    } else if (check == 1) {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        print(check)


    }else   if (check == 2) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sec1") as! quizViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


    }else {
        let vc6 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "wat") as! waterController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc6, animated: true)
    }


}
```

howdo i call the item value of the view controller

Comment: why you asked the same question in repeatedly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931170/how-do-i-call-check-value-out-of-the-function/51931573#51931573

Comment: Actually i dont understand whats your question is?

Comment: @gihanshox -  question is simple, questioner wants to pass the `item` to another `VC`

Comment: What do you want to pass to the second VC? The image displayed or the selected index (Int)?